# ?selectableItemBackground works only once..?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat

So I'm having a bit of trouble with an Android project in production.

This problem has persisted through the last few months, spanning over many appcompat and gradle versions, and I haven't found anyone else talking about this issue anywhere.

**Story Time:**

I have "?selectableItemBackground" set all over the app at different places. (as the background of course)

The problem I'm having is that the ripple effect fires ONLY ONCE per activity, but ONLY if the view/button started another activity.

**Example:**

1. Click a button that opens an AlertDialog or does some action inside the "Activity A" (ripple works)
2. Click the same button, or another button, all is good (ripple works)
3. Click a button that opens a new activity (Activity B) (ripple still works)
4. Close "Activity B"
5. All Ripple effects stop working in "Activity A"

**Any ideas would be appreciated :)**

Comment: Can you post a simple project at github demostrating that behavior?

Comment: The problem is it doesn't happen in any of my little projects. only on this big one, which I cannot make public - for legal reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently we were clearing all the views' backgrounds, everytime `onStop()` was called, so when you come back - none of the clickable backgrounds would be attached.

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: just had to stop clearing the background in the `onStop`

Answer (score 0):

make sure these in to the layout

```
        android:clickable="true"

        android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
```

Comment: I have the clickable attribute set to true, and just for sanity check, I tried moving the "?selectableItemBackground" into the foreground instead of the background. Still the same.

Answer (score 0):

add following code

android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:clickable="true"